# Camera data bytes[] always in landscape mode?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have created a camera app and using the data to do something .But the data is always in landscape mode .

I have tried this which is making the preview in portrait mode but the byte[] I am getting still gives me a landscape photo.

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

I know I can make it as a bitmap and rotate it 90 but I need only the data from onPictureTaken.

I also tried

```
param.setRotation(90);
```

Which is not working on some of the devices.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is how camera API works (unlike iOS). There are some efficient methods that can rotate the pixels to portrait if you really need this, but they never come at 0 cost. So the best practice is to adjust your code that processes the arriving preview frames.

Comment: Hmm ya. I may need to adjust the code then.. Tnx for the clarification.